# In UWP XAML, why does x:DataType fail to find a type from a .NET Standard class library?

Tags: uwp, .net-standard

Background: I'm using Visual Studio 2017 v15.3.3. My UWP project is targeting Windows Creators Update 15063, and references NuGet package `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform v5.4.0`. In my solution I also have a .NET Standard 1.4 class library that the UWP app references.

In my UWP app, I have the following XAML code for my ListView:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="x:DataType="lib:Class1">
...
</DataTemplate>
```

(I have the appropriate using statement: `xmlns:lib="using:NetStandard14Lib"`)

Everything compiles fine and runs. At runtime I successfully see my collection displayed with that DataTemplate.

However at design-time I get the following error:

```
The name "Class1" does not exist in the namespace "using:NetStandard14Lib".
```

I have also tried making the class library .NET Standard 1.3 but to no avail. Same with 1.2. However, the problem seems to resolve itself when I target .NET Standard 1.1 or 1.0.

I do not wish to downgrade to v1.1 just for a design-time error. Is there some workaround that is required for .NET Standard 1.4?

I have also tried adding to the .csproj file:

```
<PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-win+net45+wp8+win81+wpa8</PackageTargetFallback>
```

**Update**

I was able to work around this issue by removing `x:DataType` from my `DataTemplate`s altogether. A consequence of this is that `x:Bind` no longer works, and therefore I had to fallback on regular old `Binding` until a proper solution comes along

Comment: I found this error, too. I couldnt find a normal solution, i just moved the class to the namespace that points to: 'xmlns:lib="this_namespace". Hope that helps...

Comment: thanks. I also found a work-around (see update) that might help too

Comment: @BCA I don't recommend downgrading your NuGet package to fix design time errors. As you discovered it builds and runs just fine. I recommend reporting it here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html